# React: Is it ok to check cookies for refresh token?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have create a log in page, which has to enter `username` and `password` to authenticate. After the authentication, I `push` the `history` to the `Homepage` by using `react-router` and set a `cookie`. The code is like:

```
const handleLogin = () =>{
        const options = {
            url: "http://test/login",
            method: "POST",
            withCredentials: true,
            headers:{
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "content-Type": "application/json;charset-UTF-8"
            },
            data: {
                "username": user,
                "password": pass,
            }
        };
        Axios(options).then(Response =>{
            if(Response.data.JWT){
                let decode = jwt_decode(Response.data.JWT);
                if(decode.id){
                    setLoginUser(decode.username);
                    setAuthenticated(true);
                    history.push('/Homepage');
                    Cookies.set("isLogged", {expires: 1} )
                }
            }else{
                alert("Invalid user");
            }  
        });
    }
```

I also used JWT from back-end, here the application is fine. But when I refresh the web page, I check through the cookies for the refresh token to stay in the Homepage, and remove it for log out.

```
const readCookie = () => {
    let user = false;
    if(user = Cookies.get("isLogged")){
        history.push('/Homepage');
        setAuthenticated(true);
    }else{
        history.push('/');
    }
}
useEffect(() => {
    readCookie()
},[]);
```

Is it OK to get refresh token like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function, on the outside, should be a dependency of your `useEffect`. To avoid that, just move it inside the hook. Other than that, looks good to me. Reading a cookie is a side-effect, so you're doing it the right way.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const readCookie = () => {
    let user = false;
    if(user = Cookies.get("isLogged")){
        history.push('/Homepage');
        setAuthenticated(true);
    }else{
        history.push('/');
    }
  }

  readCookie()
},[]);
```

If you wanted to leave `readCookies` outside of the hook, you'll have to wrap it in a `useCallback` hook and use that in your dependency, like so:

```
const readCookiesCallback = useCallback(() => {/* your read cookies code */}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  readCookiesCallback()
}, [readCookiesCallback])
```

For what you're doing, that's unnecessary. My first example is the way to go.